# Change background on jpeg/pdf

Tags: color, pdf, background, jpg

I purchased a file online for an invitation that is a jpeg and pdf. I love the design but hoped to change the background from a cream to a chalkboard look. (I suppose I’ll find clip art or stock photo for that.)

I am able to edit text in these files using corjl but can someone help me—am I able to change the background there or need to import it into Illustrator?  How can I do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Designers and customers seem to meet in this site. A designer asks how to prevent customers to edit his designs and a customer asks how to edit designer's design. Actually the designer has the law behind him.  In many countries making and distributing derivative versions is illegal without written permission of the copyright owner. Distribute = make freely visible for others or sell or give to others for free.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the point you are making. I did reach out to the original designer and she was gave me permission. When I had trouble, she ended up unlocking that layer. Problem solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually some PDF Files have the layers information added, so if it is the case, you can edit these layers.
what i usually do, is  go illustrator open the PDF file, right click and ungroup the illustration, then you can select the background and change the color or fill it with a gradient or other image instead.

With JPG files, there are no way to manipulate the art, since the file is a flat image and doesn't have any info about layers and other atributtes.

Comment: Thank you for your help!